# Cancel coroutines in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, kotlin-coroutines

I was wondering how to deal with coroutines cancelation in a `BroadcastReceiver`. I have to run some `suspend`ing methods and for the moment I am using a `GlobalScope.launch` or a `runBlocking`. Is there another way in order to control the job that is being fired and cancel when the `BroadcastReceiver()` is finished? It's an `AlarmManager` specifically.

For all saying to switch to a `WorkManager` the answer is no because I'm scheduling work at exact time and `WorkManager` doesn't do that for you. So in order to set `Alarms` I have to read some data from a `suspend` method once the `AlarmManager` is fired. I also tried this solution:

```
//inside Alarm Managers onReceive Method

val job = coroutineScope.launch {
    delayingOperationMethod()
}

job.invokeOnCompletion {
    coroutineScope.cancel()
}
```

Where `job` is just:

```
private val job: Job = Job()
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.IO)
```

Is this a way of doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the `GlobalScope` was the best solution:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
 ///
}
```

Comment: But this does not block thread, `onReceive` will return immediately and BroadcastReceiver will die before `launch` completes?

Comment: `GlobalScope` won't die ofc even `BroadcastReceiver` dies, unless App process dies immediately